# MirageJS not persisting POST created data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocking, miragejs

I'm building this VueJS app with MirageJS to mock an API and I came up with this issue. I have a `/users` endpoint where it handles GET and POST requests. If data is created by a factory, it returns this data. If data is created by a POST request, in a form, I receive a `Created - 201` message but when I make a GET request again, this POST created data isn't there. Does MirageJS only persists data created by a factory?

Here is the code

[image]

This server dump returns the created data, but when I make a another GET request, it is empty.

Demo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeeBJ.jpg

Comment: Nope, what you have looks right. `schema.users.create(attrs)` will create a db record.

Try adding a debugger at the end of your POST handler and run `server.db.dump()` to see if the new data is in the database. Also if you upload a reproduction I can take a look!